# Wicked PDF silently fails on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, wicked-pdf

With the same code and gem versions, it works just fine in Ubuntu (14.04, 64bit). Currently I am using:

- `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem v0.9.9.1
- `wicked_pdf` gem v0.10.2
- Rails 4.1.1
- Ruby 2.1.3
- OS X 10.10, **64-bit**

When I tried to generate PDF from Rails, i get the error message: `wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386 quit unexpectedly`. Here's the full error message:

```
Process:               wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386 [1208]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386
Identifier:            wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ruby [1207]
Responsible:           Terminal [560]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2014-11-18 13:57:49.082 +0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        FE32CAE5-D54C-30C5-5D5E-6B3F12C58027

Sleep/Wake UUID:       83991D0B-AAA7-4EE0-8FF7-5034B78B788F

Time Awake Since Boot: 8000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1100 seconds

Crashed Thread:        Unknown

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000001

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x015382c8  ebx: 0x00d8c971  ecx: 0x00000001  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x015382b4  ebp: 0xbfff6428  esp: 0xbfff6040
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010246  eip: 0x00d8e3c2   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000001

Logical CPU:     3
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 3109
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
```

The reason why I said **silently** in the title, is because when I inspected the server log it's running just fine. Here's an excerpt:

```
"***************\"/Users/david/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf\" -q  --footer-html \"file:////var/folders/4w/fybp8mln1pn91cqrxq6z2kcc0000gp/T/wicked_footer_pdf20141118-1102-1uce4hg.html\"     --margin-bottom 13    \"file:////var/folders/4w/fybp8mln1pn91cqrxq6z2kcc0000gp/T/wicked_pdf20141118-1102-1jrv3s8.html\" \"/var/folders/4w/fybp8mln1pn91cqrxq6z2kcc0000gp/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20141118-1102-qu51nc.pdf\" ***************"
  Rendered text template (1.1ms)
Sent data test.pdf (8.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6516ms (Views: 7.5ms | ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
```

Running `which wkhtmltopdf` gives me `/Users/david/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf`.. When I ran tested wkhtmltopdf separately (as in `wkhtmltopdf test1.html test1.pdf`) it runs perfectly.

Is it possible that `wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386` doesn't work well in 64-bit based architecture? (Even though my Ubuntu is also 64-bit based.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done this? :

create/edit file:

**config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb**

```
If your wkhtmltopdf executable is not on your webserver's path, you can configure it in an initializer:

WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/Users/USER/*/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386'
}
```

[soure](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)

Comment: Problem is, the wkhtmltopdf executes but quit unexpectedly.. That should mean that the executable is found, but something causes it to exit, right? Btw, I just updated my question :)